# Two way replication between SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that in SQL Server you can't have two-way replication between different versions.

But, I want to know, Is it possible to perform two way replication between SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 if they are considered "different versions"?

Did anyone try to build a replication between those 2 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do the replication as they are not differnt versions but they are different service packs.

From the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx):

> When you replicate between or among different versions of SQL Server,
> you are usually limited to the functionality of the earliest version
> used. For example, if you upgrade a Distributor to an instance of SQL
> Server 2008, but you have a Publisher that is running an instance of
> SQL Server 2005 and a Subscriber that is running an instance of SQL
> Server 2000, you are limited to the general functionality and
> replication functionality of SQL Server 2000.
>
> For all types of replication, the Distributor version must be no
> earlier than the Publisher version. (Frequently, the Distributor is
> the same instance as the Publisher.)
>
> For transactional replication, a
> Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within
> two versions of the Publisher version. For example, a SQL Server 2000
> Publisher can have SQL Server 2008 Subscribers, and a SQL Server 2008
> Publisher can have SQL Server 2000 Subscribers.
>
> For merge replication,
> a Subscriber to a merge publication can be any version no later than
> the Publisher version. For more information about compatibility for
> earlier versions, see "Compatibility Level for Merge Publications"
> later in this topic. For more information about replication features
> that are supported in the various editions of SQL Server, see Features
> Supported by the Editions of SQL Server "Denali".